# runtime analysis - recursive functiokn example

Tags: python, recursion, runtime, analysis

I had to check the runtime of this function. I know the answer is j-i but i dont understand why.

assume j>=i

```
def  my_sum(i,j):
    if i == j:
        return i
    mid = (i + j)//2
    return my_sum(i, mid) + my_sum(mid + 1, j)
```

does anyone has any idea why?

Comment: Most of all, the answer is *not* j-i.  Please show the work you've done to analyze the code; "i don't understand why" is not much of a problem specification.  It appears that you haven't run the code, traced the operation, or hand-simulated it.  Please do so and describe your findings and your remaining confusion.

Comment: this is a question from a test. after the test they published that this is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

edit:

my bad, didnt realize you were using "//"

what seems to be the issue is the return

you are using:

```
return my_sum(i, mid) + my_sum(mid + 1, j)
```

lets take the example case, i=2, j=4:

What happens:

```
if i == j: ## false nothing happens here
    return i  
mid = (i + j)//2  ## mid = (2+4)//2 = 3
return my_sum(i, mid) + my_sum(mid + 1, j) ## return my_sum(2,3) + my_sum(4,4)

my_sum (2,3):
....
mid = (2+3)//2 = 2
return my_sum (2,2) + my_sum(3,3) = 2 + 3 = 5

my_sum(4,4) = 4
```

so:

```
my_sum (2,3) + my_sum(4,4) = 5 + 4 = 9
```

which is problaby not what you wanted.

so the issue here is to problaby set the return value